# Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to build a SpringBoot application.

```
   package com.uni.authorize;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthorizeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorizeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

But, when I try to run the app, it throws me the below error:

```
2020-03-28 20:39:36.765 ERROR 19071 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.uni.authorize.AuthorizeApplication.main(AuthorizeApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5068) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2020-03-28 20:39:36.775 ERROR 19071 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.uni.authorize.AuthorizeApplication.main(AuthorizeApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5068) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2020-03-28 20:39:36.779  INFO 19071 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-03-28 20:39:36.935  WARN 19071 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-03-28 20:39:37.037  INFO 19071 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-28 20:39:37.143 ERROR 19071 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1321)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/talha/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/home/talha/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/home/talha/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

my current pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.uni</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorize</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>authorize</name>
    <description>API for user registration and login with validation</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jsontoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsontoken</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>authrize</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This application is for login and registrtaion, but when i try creating token for login i get the error mentioned above.
My CreateToken code is as below:

```
package com.uni.authorize.service;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Instant;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.uni.authorize.model.TokenKeys;
import com.uni.authorize.pojo.TokenObject;
import com.uni.authorize.repository.TokenKeysRepository;
import com.uni.authorize.service.CreateToken;

import net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonToken;
import net.oauth.jsontoken.crypto.HmacSHA256Signer;

public class CreateToken {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreateToken.class);

    private static final String ISSUER = "UnI United Tech";

    @Autowired
    TokenKeysRepository tokenKeyRepository;

    public TokenObject createToken(String userId) {

        List<TokenKeys> tokenList = tokenKeyRepository.findAll();
        TokenKeys tokenKeys = tokenList.get(0);

        long accessTokenValidity = tokenKeys.getAccessTokenValidity();
        long refreshTokenValidiry = tokenKeys.getRefreshTokenValidity();

        String accessTokenKey = tokenKeys.getAccessKey();

        String refreshTokenKey = tokenKeys.getRefreshKey();

        String accessToken = generateAccessToken(userId, accessTokenKey, accessTokenValidity);
        String refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(userId, refreshTokenKey, refreshTokenValidiry);

        TokenObject tokenObject = new TokenObject();

        tokenObject.setAccess_token(accessToken);
        tokenObject.setRefresh_token(refreshToken);
        tokenObject.setToken_type("bearer");
        tokenObject.setExpires_in(accessTokenValidity);
        tokenObject.setScope("read write trust");
        return tokenObject;
    }

    private String generateAccessToken(String userId, String accessTokenKey, long accessTokenValidity) {

        HmacSHA256Signer signer;

        try {
            signer = new HmacSHA256Signer(ISSUER, null, accessTokenKey.getBytes());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Configure JSON token
        JsonToken token = new net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonToken(signer);
        // token.setAudience(AUDIENCE);

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

        long dateTimeMillis = dateTime.getMillis();

//      DateTime currentTimeDateTime = new DateTime(dateTimeMillis);
//      DateTime expiryTimeDateTime = new DateTime(dateTimeMillis + accessTokenValidity);

        Instant currentTimeInstant = new org.joda.time.Instant(dateTimeMillis);
        Instant expirationTimeInstant = new org.joda.time.Instant(dateTimeMillis + accessTokenValidity);

        LOGGER.debug("Current Time Instant" + currentTimeInstant);
        LOGGER.debug("Expiration Tine Instant" + expirationTimeInstant);

        token.setIssuedAt(currentTimeInstant);
        token.setExpiration(expirationTimeInstant);

        // Configure request object, which provides information of the item
        JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
        request.addProperty("userId", userId);

        JsonObject payload = token.getPayloadAsJsonObject();
        payload.add("info", request);

        try {
            return token.serializeAndSign();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String generateRefreshToken(String userId, String refreshTokenKey, long refreshTokenValidiry) {
        HmacSHA256Signer signer;

        try {
            signer = new HmacSHA256Signer(ISSUER, null, refreshTokenKey.getBytes());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Configure JSON token
        JsonToken token = new net.oauth.jsontoken.JsonToken(signer);
        // token.setAudience(AUDIENCE);

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

        long dateTimeMillis = dateTime.getMillis();

//      DateTime currentTimeDateTime = new DateTime(dateTimeMillis);
//      DateTime expiryTimeDateTime = new DateTime(dateTimeMillis + refreshTokenValidiry);

        Instant currentTimeInstant = new org.joda.time.Instant(dateTimeMillis);
        Instant expirationTimeInstant = new org.joda.time.Instant(dateTimeMillis + refreshTokenValidiry);

        LOGGER.debug("Current Time Instant" + currentTimeInstant);
        LOGGER.debug("Expiration Tine Instant" + expirationTimeInstant);

        token.setIssuedAt(currentTimeInstant);
        token.setExpiration(expirationTimeInstant);

        // Configure request object, which provides information of the item
        JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
        request.addProperty("userId", userId);

        JsonObject payload = token.getPayloadAsJsonObject();
        payload.add("info", request);

        try {
            return token.serializeAndSign();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

If i remove the following dependency and the class CreateToke the application runs fine , but as the CreateToken is removed the token is not created.The following are the dependencies which i remove for the code to run:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jsontoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsontoken</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please let me know where am going wrong.
**Thanks in advance for helping**

Comment: As you use `Autowired` annotation so add a `Stereotype` on your class like below:

@Component
public class CreateToken {}
    or
@Configuration
public class CreateToken {}

Comment: Hi Nasir,Sry this did not work.. Still getting th esame error